# Unable to get sublist of a list

Tags: java

Im trying to get a sublist of a list but for some reason the sublist prints only
4 items instead of 8.

```
        String s1 = "{{ (( 4 + 5 )) }}";
        System.out.println("Length of string = " + s1.length());
        String[] s2 = s1.split(""); //Split the string into array
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(s2)); //Convert the array into list
        al.remove(0); //remove the first occurence
        TreeSet hs = new TreeSet(al.subList(1, 8)); //Create a hashset with only first 8 elements
```

output

```
Length of string = 17
al list =  [{, {,  , (, (,  , 4,  , +,  , 5,  , ), ),  , }, }]
length of the list= 17
al list subset =  [ , (, 4, {]
length of the al subset= 4
```

Comment: Any hashset only stores distinct items

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using a Set data type. Sets do not allow duplicates. The 4 items printed are the only 4 unique elements from index 1 - 8 in your example.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is you're only grabbing 7 items, not 8. Also, you may want to look into the constructor of `TreeSet` to see what happens with duplicate values in the constructor. Spoiler, they don't keep duplicates :-)

```
System.out.println("al after removal: " + al);

List<String> a2 = (List<String>) al.subList(1, 8);

System.out.println("Size of a2: " + a2.size());
System.out.println("a2: " + a2);
```

Output:

> al after removal: [{,  , (, (,  , 4,  , +,  , 5,  , ), ),  , }, }]
>   Size of a2: 7 
>   a2: [ , (, (,  , 4,  , +]